# How to rotate colors on each call to my custom command?

Tags: color

I'm trying to do this:

```
\print{Hello!} % to be printed in red
\print{How are you?} % to be printed in green
\print{I'm good!} % to be printed in blue
\print{Bye!} % again in red
```

I simply want `\print` command to pick the next color from a pre-defined "pallette" (list of colors). When the pallette is finished, it should start from the first one. How is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a naïve implementation. It uses the `\ifcase` construction to go through the values of a counter and set the color accordingly. When we get to the last one we reset. Note that counters are sowhat global in latex.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcounter{colrot}
\newcommand\print[1]{%
  \stepcounter{colrot}%
  \ifcase\value{colrot}\relax% 0 ignoreed
  \or\color{red}% 1
  \or\color{green}% 2
  \or\color{blue}\setcounter{colrot}{0}% 3
  \fi%
  #1%
}
\begin{document}

\print{Hello!} % to be printed in red
\print{How are you?} % to be printed in green
\print{I'm good!} % to be printed in blue
\print{Bye!} % again in red

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This keeps a stack of colors and cycles every time `\print` is used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\colorlist{{red}{green}{blue}{black}{purple}}
\newcommand\print[1]{%
    \expandafter\textcolor\expandafter{\expandafter\@car\colorlist\@nil}{#1}%
    \edef\colorlist{\expandafter\@cdr\colorlist\@nil {\expandafter\@car\colorlist\@nil}}%
}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
\print{foo} \print{bar} \print{baz} \print{foo} \print{bar} \print{baz}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

However, the number of colors must be at least 3, or some braces will be stripped.
For 2 colors a simple switch suffices:

```
\let\printaux=A
\newcommand\print[1]{\if A\printaux \let\printaux=B\textcolor{red}{#1}\else \let\printaux=A\textcolor{blue}{#1}\fi}
```